# Consul connect injector cannot connect to my consul server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, consul, servicemesh

if i deploy a instance of a consul client using the consul helm chart into my k3s cluster. The connect-injector pod will not start properly.

k3s version: k3s version v1.25.6+k3s1 (9176e03c) 
Helm version: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.12.1", GitCommit:"f32a527a060157990e2aa86bf45010dfb3cc8b8d", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.20.4"} 
Terraform version: Terraform v1.5.2 
Consul Version: v1.16 
Docker compose version: Docker Compose version v2.19.1 
Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.4
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.5
 Git commit:        3713ee1
 Built:             Fri Jul  7 14:50:55 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.4
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.5
  Git commit:       4ffc614
  Built:            Fri Jul  7 14:50:55 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

This is my consul server.hcl file

```
server           = true
bootstrap        = false
bootstrap_expect = 1

node_name  = "dev-consul"
datacenter = "dev-dc"

encrypt                 = "<encrypt-key>"
encrypt_verify_incoming = true
encrypt_verify_outgoing = true

tls {
  defaults {
    ca_file         = "/consul/config/certs/consul-agent-ca.pem"
    cert_file       = "/consul/config/certs/dev-dc-server-consul-0.pem"
    key_file        = "/consul/config/certs/dev-dc-server-consul-0-key.pem"
    verify_incoming = true
    verify_outgoing = true
  }
}

data_dir  = "/consul-data"
log_level = "INFO"

advertise_addr = "<advertise-addr>"
bind_addr      = "0.0.0.0"

addresses = {
  "http" = "0.0.0.0"
}

auto_encrypt = {
  "allow_tls" = true
}

connect = {
  "enabled" = true
}

ui_config = {
  "enabled" = true
}
```

I'm using this docker compose file to deploy my server node:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  consul:
    image: hashicorp/consul:1.16
    volumes:
      - ./config/server.hcl:/consul/config/server.hcl:ro
      - consul_data:/titanium/consul-data
      - ./certs:/consul/config/certs/
    ports:
      - "8600:8600/tcp"
      - "8600:8600/udp"
      - "8500:8500/tcp"
      - "8500:8500/udp"
      - "8301:8301/tcp"
      - "8301:8301/udp"
      - "8302:8302/tcp"
      - "8302:8302/udp"
      - "8502:8502"
      - "21000-21255:21000-21255"
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8300:8300/udp"
    command: "agent"

volumes:
  consul_data:
```

The consul server is working good so far. When i use the consul helm chart with the following values.yml

```yaml
global:
  name: consul
  image: hashicorp/consul:1.16
  domain: dev.local
  datacenter: dev-dc
  exposeGossipPorts: true
  gossipEncryption:
    secretName: "gossip-encryption-key-secret"
    secretKey: "key"
  tls:
    enabled: true
    enableAutoEncrypt: true
    verify: true
    caCert:
      secretName: "consul-certs"
      secretKey: "ca.pem"
connectInject:
  enabled: true
  default: true
  cni:
    enabled: true
    logLevel: info
    cniBinDir: "/opt/cni/bin"
    cniNetDir: "/etc/cni/net.d"
  namespaceSelector: |
    matchLabels:
      connect-inject : enabled
  failurePolicy: "Ignore"
server:
  enabled: false
client:
  enabled: true
  join: [ "<consul-service-addr>" ]
  grpc: true
```

With the following values the consul client will connect to the cluster but the pod containing the consul-connect-injector will give me the following error message

`2023-07-23T19:23:44.851Z [INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager: trying to connect to a Consul server 2023-07-23T19:23:44.854Z [ERROR] consul-server-connection-manager: connection error: error="failed to discover Consul server addresses: failed to resolve DNS name: consul-server.consul.svc: lookup consul-server.consul.svc on 10.43.0.10:53: no such host`

If i check the kubernetes events of the pod i will get errors like this:

`MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "consul-ca-cert`
`MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "certs" : secret "consul-connect-inject-webhook-cert" not found`.

I create the secrets for the gossip encryption key and the tls cert via a kubernetes resource file.

I don't think its neccessary to know but this is the terraform script i use:

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "consul-connect" {
  name       = "consul-connect"
  chart      = "consul"
  repository = "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com"
  namespace  = "consul"

  values = [file("config/values.yml")]
}
```

I've tried to modify my values.yml multiple times but the connect-injector pod was printing the same error message over and over again. I've also tried to use a simplified values.yml

```yaml
global:
  name: consul
  domain: dev.local
  datacenter: dev-dc
  gossipEncryption:
    secretName: "gossip-encryption-key-secret"
    secretKey: "key"
  tls:
    enabled: true
    enableAutoEncrypt: true
    verify: true
    caCert:
      secretName: "consul-certs"
      secretKey: "ca.pem"
connectInject:
  enabled: true
  failurePolicy: "Ignore"
controller:
  enabled: true
server:
  enabled: false
client:
  enabled: true
  image: hashicorp/consul:1.15.3
  join: [ "<consul-server-addr>" ]
```

But even that has not changed anything. I also tried to install a consul server via the helm chart but it didn't fix my problem with the connect-injector-pod.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it tries to reach consul-server.consul.svc which is disabled in your configuration.

I would try to enable externalServers and set `externalServers.hosts` to the same value as `client.join`